# C++ split string by line

Tags: c++, split

I need to split string by line.
I used to do in the following way:

```
int doSegment(char *sentence, int segNum)
{
assert(pSegmenter != NULL);
Logger &log = Logger::getLogger();
char delims[] = "\n";
char *line = NULL;
if (sentence != NULL)
{
    line = strtok(sentence, delims);
    while(line != NULL)
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        line = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }
}
else
{
    log.error("....");
}
return 0;
}
```

I input "we are one.\nyes we are." and invoke the doSegment method. But when i debugging, i found the sentence parameter is "we are one.\\nyes we are", and the split failed. Can somebody tell me why this happened and what should i do. Is there anyway else i can use to split string in C++. thanks !

Comment: I suggest using real c++ - have a look at std::getline

Comment: You need to make some change about the input. Not the split function.

Comment: Be careful with `strtok` as it modifies the string you pass to it.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I'd like to use std::getline or std::string::find to go through the string.
below code demonstrates getline function

```
int doSegment(char *sentence)
{
  std::stringstream ss(sentence);
  std::string to;

  if (sentence != NULL)
  {
    while(std::getline(ss,to,'\n')){
      cout << to <<endl;
    }
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: one more question. I was not sure whether the stringstream  need to close .

Comment: it's local variable, it will destruct itself if gets out of doSegment.

Answer (score 21):

You can call [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) in a loop and the use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

```
std::vector<std::string> split_string(const std::string& str,
                                      const std::string& delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings;

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type prev = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find(delimiter, prev)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        strings.push_back(str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
        prev = pos + delimiter.size();
    }

    // To get the last substring (or only, if delimiter is not found)
    strings.push_back(str.substr(prev));

    return strings;
}
```

See example [here](http://ideone.com/UHWNQW).

Comment: If you are using a delimiter that has more than one character, like I am, you will want to change the "prev = pos + 1;" line to "prev = pos + delimiter.size();" instead.  Otherwise, you'll have the remaining characters left over in the beginning of the next element in the vector.

Answer (score 20):

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split_string_by_newline(const std::string& str)
{
    auto result = std::vector<std::string>{};
    auto ss = std::stringstream{str};

    for (std::string line; std::getline(ss, line, '\n');)
        result.push_back(line);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work with or without C++ 11.  "error: too many initializers for 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}|"

Comment: You might check here https://godbolt.org/z/3axvrx that it works.

Comment: @dan-donnelly, I also had that error.  Turns out I had forgotten to #include <sstream>.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
    
using namespace std;


vector<string> splitter(string in_pattern, string& content){
    vector<string> split_content;

    regex pattern(in_pattern);
    copy( sregex_token_iterator(content.begin(), content.end(), pattern, -1),
    sregex_token_iterator(),back_inserter(split_content));  
    return split_content;
}
    
int main()
{   

    string sentence = "This is the first line\n";
    sentence += "This is the second line\n";
    sentence += "This is the third line\n";

    vector<string> lines = splitter(R"(\n)", sentence);

    for (string line: lines){cout << line << endl;}

}
```

1. We have a string with multiple lines
2. we split those into an array (vector)
3. We print out those elements in a for loop

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using the library [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split_string_by_newline(const std::string_view str) {
  return str | ranges::views::split('\n')
             | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();
}
```

Using C++23 ranges:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split_string_by_newline(const std::string_view str) {
  return str | std::ranges::views::split('\n')
             | std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This fairly inefficient way just loops through the string until it encounters an \n newline escape character. It then creates a substring and adds it to a vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> Loader::StringToLines(std::string string)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string temp;
    int markbegin = 0;
    int markend = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {     
        if (string[i] == '\n') {
            markend = i;
            result.push_back(string.substr(markbegin, markend - markbegin));
            markbegin = (i + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: doesn't properly handle no trailing newline