# Stack overflow during std::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, stl

I'm trying to execute the following C++ STL-based code to replace text in a relatively large SQL script (~8MB):

```
std::basic_regex<TCHAR> reProc("^[ \t]*create[ \t]+(view|procedure|proc)+[ \t]+(.+)$\n((^(?![ \t]*go[ \t]*).*$\n)+)^[ \t]*go[ \t]*$");
std::basic_string<TCHAR> replace = _T("ALTER $1 $2\n$3\ngo");
return std::regex_replace(strInput, reProc, replace);
```

The result is a stack overflow, and it's hard to find information about that particular error on this particular site since that's also the name of the site.

**Edit:** I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

**Edit 2:** The original file is over 23,000 lines. I cut the file down to 3,500 lines and still get the error. When I cut it by another ~50 lines down to 3,456 lines, the error goes away. If I put just those cut lines into the file, the error is still gone. This suggests that the error is not related to specific text, but just too much of it.

**Edit 3:** A full *working* example is demonstrated operating properly here:
https://regex101.com/r/iD1zY6/1
It doesn't work in that STL code, though.

Comment: do you know the `strInput` that triggers the stack overflow?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yes, but I'm not sure how to share such a large input string. I don't want to put 8 MB of text in the question.

Comment: your regex is bounded by line (`"^...$"`) Is the file all one line? or is there a single line that triggers it? or is it only when processing the whole file at once what triggers it?

Comment: I added a link to a page on regex101 that includes the shortest version of the input string that causes the error.

Comment: IMO you should replace this complicated regex by a loop over the lines - `std::find_if` for "create (view|proc)", `std::find_if` for "go", grab everything in-between and do your replacement this way.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Unfortunately I'm very unfamiliar with STL. If you could demonstrate that in an answer, I'd love to try it.

Comment: Is this me or you just want to change `create` to `alter` for each procedure/view ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I think that sums it up.

Comment: It might be naive, but isn't [this](https://regex101.com/r/hF0uP8/1) an acceptable solution (even if it doesn't solve the SOE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that STL regular expressions are tragic under-performers versus Perl (about 100 times slower if you can believe https://stackoverflow.com/a/37016671/78162), so it's apparently necessary to absolutely minimize the use of regular expressions in STL/C++ when performance is a serious concern. (The degree to which C++/STL under-performs here blew my mind considering I presume C++ to generally be one of the more performant languages). I ended up passing the file stream to read one line at a time and only run the expression on lines that needed processing like this:

```
   std::basic_string<TCHAR> result;
   std::basic_string<TCHAR> line;
   std::basic_regex<TCHAR> reProc(_T("^[ \t]*create[ \t]+(view|procedure|proc)+[ \t]+(.+)$"), std::regex::optimize);
   std::basic_string<TCHAR> replace = _T("ALTER $1 $2");

   do {
      std::getline(input, line);
      int pos = line.find_first_not_of(_T(" \t"));
      if ((pos != std::basic_string<TCHAR>::npos) 
          && (_tcsnicmp(line.substr(pos, 6).data(), _T("create"), 6)==0))
         result.append(std::regex_replace(line, reProc, replace));
      else
         result.append(line);
      result.append(_T("\n"));
   } while (!input.eof());
   return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following trimmed-down version of your regex saves about 20% of processing steps according to regex101 (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6oA4/2)).

```
\\bcreate[ \t]+(view|procedure|proc)[ \t]+(.+)\n(((?![ \t]*go[ \t]*).*\n)+)[ \t]*go[ \t]*
```

Modifications:

- inline anchors removed: you are expressly testing for newline characters
- repetition operator for the db object keywords removed - a repetition at this point would make the original script syntactically invalid.
- initial whitespace pattern replaced by word boundary (note the double backslash - the escape sequence is for the regex engine, not for the compiler)

If you can be sure that ...

- the `create ...` statements do not occur in string literals, and
- you do not need to distinguish between  `create ...` statements followed by a `go` or not (eg. because all statements are trailed by a `go`)

...it might even be easier to just replace these strings:

```
std::basic_regex<TCHAR> reProc("\bcreate[ \t]+(view|procedure|proc)");
std::basic_string<TCHAR> replace = _T("ALTER $1");
return std::regex_replace(strInput, reProc, replace);
```

([Here](https://regex101.com/r/cP9fD1/2) is a demo for the latter approach - reduces the steps to a little more than 1/4 th).

Comment: The "\b" at the beginning seems to be preventing the STL regex from matching a `create` at the beginning of a line for some reason. Need a double \\ I assume.

Comment: It seems this solution is still going to be far too slow. If I were writing C# code I would split it up by "\ngo\n" and replace in each component. But I don't know how to do that in STL. It's been running more than a minute and still not done, and I think VB6 was able to do this in less than a minute by processing it one line at a time (I'm rewriting some old code). I thought I could simplify the code by processing it all at once, but the cost turns out to be too high. I don't even know how to split up text into lines with STL.

Comment: So maybe splitting as suggested in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13172514) would help? The text portions to be replaced do not appear to span lines.

Comment: The demo from the abovementioned answer adjusted to your sample input is online [here](http://ideone.com/GsKGyJ)