# Why does calling std::getline() n times on the same input deliver the nth tokenization?

Tags: c++, getline

This is a follow-up question to the accepted answer to this question: [C++ split string by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172158/c-split-string-by-line)

In the following code, (function `doSegment()` is quoted from answerer @billz):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int doSegment( const char *sentence )
{
  std::stringstream ss(sentence);
  std::string to;

  if (sentence != NULL)
  {
    while(std::getline(ss,to,'\n')){
      std::cout << to << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "hello\nworld" << std::endl << "my" << std::endl << "name" << std::endl << "is nobody";
  doSegment( oss.str().c_str() );
  return 0;
}
```

...the code behaves exactly as expected: it tokenizes the input string on newlines

**Question:** Why does calling `std::getline()` iteratively on the same input argument result in the *next* tokenization stored to the output argument? I.e. how does `std::getline()` keep track that it's been called *n* times and needs to deliver the *(n + 1)th* tokenization?

I.e. as comparison, `strtok()` does this by having you pass `NULL` as the input argument so that it knows to operate on its static local variable - but it modifies its input. This exampled use of `std::getline()` neither requires passing NULL as the input after the first iteration nor does it modify its input.

I did try read the writeup of `std::getline()` at cppreference and cplusplus, but they didn't really seem to answer this question, and I didn't find quite this question existing here already.

Grateful to anyone who can enlighten me how this works.

Comment: The stream has a lot more smarts than `strtok`. Buried in the object is a read index member variable that is advanced as you extract data. Unless you rewind the pointer (eg with a `seekg` call) you will keep grabbing the next data in the stream.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, a `stringstream` behaves like both a string and a stream. Core to the behavior of a stream is that it can deliver its data to a caller who requests successive objects from it.

Comment: Read cppreference's documentation for [`std::basic_streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), which is what [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) uses internally, via a [`std::basic_stringbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf) that wraps a `std::string`.

Comment: Try doing a `doSegment(NULL);` call.  It sort of looks like the intent was `doSegment` should handle `NULL` (or `nullptr` these days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not sure where the state is stored, you can often use the simple rule of thumb by asking "What parameters can be modified?".

In the case of `std::getline()`, you can see that the first parameter is a *non-const* reference to a stream.  That is where the state is stored (in your case, in the `std::stringstream ss` object).  If `getline()` stored state elsewhere, the stream parameter would be a reference to a `const` stream instead.

You can also check the [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/istream.cc).