# Extract all directory names from a text file

Tags: c++, text-processing

I have a text file in which files names, along with their subdirectory names, could appear at any random places. E.g.

**input_file.txt**

```
This is a text file. This line has a file name and location Folder1/file1.dat appearing here.

This is another line: Folder2/file2.txt

Here is yet another line with ../Folder3/Folder4/file3.doc filename and location.
```

This will be on a Linux system; hence the forward-slashes.

I need a C++ code that can extract all the directory names/locations from this type of file. In the above example, the strings to be extracted would be:

```
Folder1
Folder2
../Folder3/Folder4
```

Given the above format of the input file, I suppose the algorithm ought to be something like this:

1. Go through each line in the file and see if the line has a forward-slash (/) anywhere in it.
2. If a forward-slash is found in a line, extract the substring between the last occurance of the forward-slash (/) in that line and the last space character that appeared before it.

I have tried several different ways, such as below, but just cannot get it to work, I am afraid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using std::cout; using std::endl;
    unsigned first, last;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease give valid file name!"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string para_file_name = argv[1];      //The name of the input file.
    std::ifstream configfile(para_file_name);

    while (getline(configfile, line)) {
       if (line.find(" ")) {
          if (line.find(" ")!=std::string::npos) first = line.find(" ");
          if (line.find("/")!=std::string::npos) last = line.find("/");
          std::string DirName = line.substr (first,last-first);
          cout << " DirName = " << DirName << endl;
       }
    }
```

The code has to be compatible with versions older than C++11 and cannot use fancy external libraries such as Boost. Just native C++ please.

Comment: "I have tried several different ways" please show a [mcve] for one of them, then we can help you to fix it

Comment: Splitting the lines has a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172514/10362622). For finding the slashes and spaces, you can use [find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) and then cut using [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Comment: @idclev463035818 OK added a solution I have tried. I should say, I don't come from a C++ background, though have experience with other, high level languages. So I am not trying to use this as a code-writing service, but rather, genuinely trying to learn and solve a problem I am stuck on.

Comment: part of a [mcve] should be the compiler error and expected and actual output. You didnt declare `configfile` and in the code you dont open any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most concise, but more performant than `<regex>` and works with C++98.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>  // exit
#include <fstream>  // fstream
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>   // getline

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "\nPlease give valid file name!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // Load the file in
    std::string line;
    std::fstream file(argv[1]);

    // For each line of file...
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string word;
        char delim = ' ';

        // For each word of line...
        while (std::getline(iss, word, delim))
        {
            size_t pos = word.find_last_of('/');

            // Word includes '/'
            if (pos != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::string dir_name = word.substr(0, pos);

                std::cout << dir_name << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Folder1
Folder2
../Folder3/Folder4
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe overkill, but you could use regex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cmatch m;
  std::regex_match("This is another line: Folder2/file2.txt", m,
                   std::regex(".*?([^/ ]+/)+.*"));

  std::cout << m.str(1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Folder2/
```