# How do I access individual numbers in a string?

Tags: c++

Say I have a string that goes:

```
199  200  208  210  200  207  240  269  260  263
```

How do I make it so if that string is called s, then s[0] = 199 (rather than 1), s[1] = 200 (rather than 9), s[2] = 208 (rather than 9), etc.  I am sorry to keep coming back here, but I really want to resolve this.

By the way, this is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int increase_altitude = 0;

    int previous = 10000;
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
    }
```

Comment: You should create a vector of string then.

Comment: Does the string have those line breaks in it. Or are we chopping in lots of 3 all the time?

Comment: Do you want numbers or strings?

Comment: You have to tokenize that string by cutting it at newlines. Optionally you convert each line from a string into a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ split string by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172158/c-split-string-by-line)

Comment: @Sebastian when I try that I get told:
"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Those linked answers also work with other delimiters than newline: space or tab.

Comment: @CSStudent *How do I make it so if that string is called s, then s[0] = 199* -- It isn't clear what you actually want to accomplish.  If `s` is a string, then `s[0]` is a single character.  If you mean you want a container (array, vector, etc) of strings from that one input string of numbers, then that makes more sense.

Comment: You have to add the code from one of the answers in the linked question to your existing one. The answers do not have a `main` function. Then you call the added function from your code. E.g. `std::vector<std::string> new_s = split_string(s, " ");` to split the string `s` at spaces.

Comment: Ok what I mean is I want 199 to be index 0 of something, 200 to be index 1, 208 to be index 2, etc @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I am sorry @Sebastian but I am very new to c++ and you, through no fault of your own, have lost me

Comment: @CSStudent *to be index 0 of something* -- So the next question, which was already asked to you -- what is this "something" made up of?  A container of strings, or a container of actual numeric values?  There is a difference between `"199"` and `199`.

Comment: Take the answer of 'a programmer dude' from the link I have given (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172158/c-split-string-by-line), add that code above yours, add `#include <vector>` on top, and add `std::vector<std::string> new_s = split_string(s, " ");` to your code. Then you can access `new_s[0]` for 199. Use `"\n"` instead of `" "` for separating by lines instead of spaces.

Comment: You can't.  A string can't hold arbitrary values in each character (in particular, with a value over 255, since a `char` is not guaranteed able to represent such values).   Create a second container (say, a vector) and parse the string to populate that array as needed.   If the second container is a `std::vector<int>` you might parse the string `"199  200  208  210  200  207  240  269  260  263"` to populate the second container with set of integral values `{199, 200, 208, 210, 200, 207, 240, 269, 260, 263}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use vector of string for this purpose,

```
std::vector <std::string> numvec;
numvec.push_back("199");
numvec.push_back("200");

// accessing the element

numvec[0] // equals to 199
```

You can take input for the vector as:

```
std::string str;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i){

    std::cin >> str;       // take input from the user  
    numvec.push_back(str); // add to the vector

}
```

However you would need to add `vector` header.

Comment: I don't believe adding it in manually like this would work for me, because the string I actually want this to work for is 1999 lines.

Comment: You can take an string input and add it to the vector.

Comment: @newdeepji I would hate to be the person who has to type in 10000 sets of numbers.

Comment: where are those data? In a file? just read those file and add it to a vector then

Comment: I tried this and it outputted only the last part of the string (263) when I tried to output the string.  What am I doing wrong?

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector <std::string> numvec;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i){
        
        std::cin >> str;       // take input from the user  
        numvec.push_back(str); // add to the vector
    }
    std::cout << str;
}

Comment: `str` is just a temporary variable to take input which we ultimately push to a vector and you are trying to print that `std::cout << str;` which will obviously display the last input number, instead use `std::cout << numvec[0]` to display first number.

Comment: There is no need for a `for` loop that pegs itself to 10000 values.  A simple `while` loop is all that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily accomplished by doing this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sVect;
    std::string s;
    while (std::cin >> s)
       sVect.push_back(s);
}
```

There is no need to hardcode any values into a `for` loop, as the `while` will terminate when there is no more input to process.